# Modsecurity error: Failed to access DBM file

Tags: ubuntu

I've also tried to create `tmp` folder, because it didn't exist.

But none of that didn't work...

Any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Is SELinux enabled?  That could prevent mod_security access to /tmp/.

Also, are you saying /tmp/ does not exist? That is highly unusual for a Linux instance.

Comment: Literally /tmp/, not /root/tmp or public_html/tmp. Permissions should be so that either its globally writable or writable by the http process.